# Oracle query to find if a column in Table has any special character anywhere in its values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to search all such values of a column which contains special characters at anyplace in it.pls help

Comment: define special characters

Comment: other than a-z,A-Z,0-9

Comment: What about `_` or `-`?

Comment: yea, also other than -

Comment: Is the percent sign `%` a special character? How about the comma or the period? There is no standardized definition of "special character" - you need to be more precise and state EXACTLY what characters you need to search for.

Comment: characters other than a-z,A-Z,0-9 and also '-'(hyphen) for my case

Answer (score 9):

This can be done using `regexp_like`.

```
select * from tbl
where regexp_like(column_name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any character not in the range of `a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`

Comment: I need to skip also values which contains '-'. I added like '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]' but its still fetching values like  A170793-BAXAC112,
 A555883-2009621. Pls help

Comment: `regexp_like(column_name,'[^a-zA-Z0-9-]')` should work.

Comment: Thnx for your help,Its working partially though, I am also getting values like- A170793-BAXAC112, how come such values r coming after using this regex. I am using this query-SELECT abc FROM t_pcrd_xyz WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(abc, '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]');

Comment: are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces? if you are unsure, try `REGEXP_LIKE(trim(abc), '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]')`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports Regexp_like(col name, expression). Let me know if you need the exact reg exp too.